# How to do custom JSON Encoding/decoding in elixir/phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m coming from php background. I’m planning to rewrite my backend api for one of my projects in Phoenix framework.

My front end is expecting for an api json response in this format

```
{
  "totalCount": 2,
  "results": [
       {
          "idUser":1,
          "name": "test"
       },
       {
          "idUser":2
          "name": "test2"
       }
  ],
  "success": true,
  .....
}
```

There are some more custom properties in the response. Is there any libraries that I can use to send the custom JSON response, without changing my front end logic.

I looked at poison library, but I’m not very sure how can I return the responses like this. I’m pretty new to Elixir/Phoenix framework. I would really appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: poison, you can try it

Comment: This is an offtopic here. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide in the first place. Also, the response example provided is **not** a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pheonix by default will use Poison. There is a helper method json that can be used like so:

```
defmodule MyController do
  use Phoenix.Controller
  def result(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:ok)
    |> json(%{"totalCount" => 2,
              "results" => [
                 %{
                   "idUser" => 1,
                   "name" => "test"
                 },
                 %{
                   "idUser" => 2,
                   "name" => "test2"
                 }
               ],
               "success" => true
            })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example.
Is that the results should be an array?

```
defmodule Test do
  def hello do
    Poison.encode!(
      %{
        "totalCount" => 2,
        "results" => [
          %{
            "idUser" => 1,
            "name" => "test"
          },
          %{
            "idUser" => 2,
            "name" => "test2"
          }
        ],
        "success" => true,
      }
    )
  end

end
Test.hello()
```